# I am iterating with a for loop and a nested for loop, and I am missing out values in the final list

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to use two four loops to extract data from a DataBlock, but for some reason the final result keeps missing the final entry for each day.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
start_time = time.time()

from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

from darksky import forecast
NYC = 'API Key',40.7128,-74.0060

date_list = a list of consecutive dates
l = len(date_list) - 1

for j in range(0,l):
nyc = forecast(*NYC, time=date_list[j])
nyc.refresh(units='si', extend='hourly')
nyc_list.append(nyc)

n = len(nyc.hourly) - 1

times = []

for j in range(0,l):
    for i in range(0,n):
    unix_times = nyc_list[j].hourly[i].time
    unix_time.append(unix_times)

for i in range(0,m):
    normal_times = time.ctime(int(unix_time[i]))
    timestamp.append(normal_times)
```

when I print out timestamp it gives the expected results, apart from the fact that the last entry from every day (the 4am one) is missing. 
--> nyc.hourly[23].time should give 4am in unix time

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue

```
l = len(date_list) - 1
```

When you use `range`, it doesn't include the last number. So `range(1,10)` would include 1-9. Remove the `-1` from the line above and it should work for you.

Comment: So I introduced the -1 because I was getting an error that said "index out of range", so I thought that I was iterating too many times.

Comment: Weird. Try removing the `-1` and printing out the index every time so you can see where the error is.

Comment: So the weird thing is that it runs until the j=72 and i=22, and doesn't work for j=72 and i=23, and doesn't work for i=23 for any date after j=72 which is the 14th of March

Comment: So if my date range is between Jan 1st and March 13th code runs fine as intended, but not if it runs beyond that. Also it has something to do with the date March 13th, rather than the length of i and j, because if i start at March 1st it still stops running when I input March 13th rather than 14th.

Comment: I asked it to print i and j as you said, but when I iterate to March 13th it prints out j=0, and goes through i values, but the last value that you would expect i=23 returns i=0

Comment: I know this is probably quite hard to debug over stackoverflow, but thanks for your help so far

Comment: Turns out that March 13th at 2am is when the clocks go back in New York State. So there is just an hour missing. Thanks for your help though